# Wordpress: How to add buttons to post edit view

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

There's a million tutorials for how to customize the TinyMCE panel on the WSYWIG editor... but that's *not* what I want to do.

I want to add a stand-alone button to the post edit view that will make an API call and auto-fill certain fields on the page. I closest I've come so far are the hooks `simple_edit_form` and `advanced_edit_form` which both allow me to add content to the very *bottom* of the edit form. It'd be much better to add it at the top, where the "add media" button lives.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an action called media buttons.  Below is basic example. I've take this example from the plugin gravity forms and changed it little.  Good luck.

```
add_action( 'media_buttons', 'add_form_button' );

function add_form_button(){
        $is_post_edit_page = in_array(RG_CURRENT_PAGE, array('post.php', 'page.php', 'page-new.php', 'post-new.php'));
        if(!$is_post_edit_page)
            return;

        // do a version check for the new 3.5 UI
        $version    = get_bloginfo('version');

        if ($version < 3.5) {
            // show button for v 3.4 and below
            $image_btn = GFCommon::get_base_url() . "/images/form-button.png";
            echo '<a href="#TB_inline?width=480&inlineId=select_gravity_form" class="thickbox" id="add_gform" title="' . __("Add Gravity Form", 'gravityforms') . '"><img src="'.$image_btn.'" alt="' . __("Add Gravity Form", 'gravityform') . '" /></a>';
        } else {
            // display button matching new UI
            echo '<style>.gform_media_icon{
                    background:url(' . GFCommon::get_base_url() . '/images/gravity-admin-icon.png) no-repeat top left;
                    display: inline-block;
                    height: 16px;
                    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
                    vertical-align: text-top;
                    width: 16px;
                    }
                    .wp-core-ui a.gform_media_link{
                     padding-left: 0.4em;
                    }
                 </style>
                  <a href="#TB_inline?width=480&inlineId=select_gravity_form" class="thickbox button gform_media_link" id="add_gform" title="' . __("Add Gravity Form", 'gravityforms') . '"><span class="gform_media_icon "></span> ' . __("Add Form", "gravityforms") . '</a>';
        }
    }
```